# Whats problem with my mesh to shrinkwrap?

Tags: modifiers

Im making eyes of spiderman. I have the mesh of face and the eyes separate with the shrinwrap modifier i want to wrap the eyes on the face. I have tried but look its a sticker im putting on the face. Not look good.
[image]

[image]

Comment: giantcowfilms has some issues.. but my guess is you are using 'project' option. If yes, orientate the eye laterally along the face

Comment: files is attached

Comment: @lemon I have tried little and fix with the project with the back and positive setting offset of 0.03. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project option projects along the normals of the object which is projected.

So here, you need to orientate the eye along the face of Spider Man:

[image]

Comment: Thanks one more small request when i go in edit mode i have the edge and i want that edges to be thick black lines is it possible

Comment: Yes.. either add an edge loop around the eye or use a texture